# Google-app-engine NDB iter keys_only

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Say I have a query that will be executed often, most likely yielding the same results.

Is it correct that using:

```
for key in qry.iter(keys_only=True):
    item = key.get()
    #do something with item
```

Would perform better than:

```
for item in qry:
    #do something with item
```

Because in the first example, the query will only load the keys and subsequent calls to `key.get()` will take advantage of NDB's caching mechanism, whereas example 2 will always fetch the entities from the store? Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would doubt that the second form would perform better -- it is always possible that the values are *not* in the cache, and then, presuming you are getting more than one entity back, you'd be making multiple roundtrips.  That quickly gets slower.

A better approach is indeed what's shown in http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118 -- use ndb.multi_get(q.fetch(keys_only=True)).  But even that is worse if your cache hit rate is too low; this is extensively discussed in the issue.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK It will not make any different, because internally, ndb caches everything, including query. If you are going to do other stuff with each one, try async api. that can save valuable time. edit : moreover, if ndb knows query in advance, it can even prefetch them.

*I have read this six months back so not sure what is current behavior.*

Comment: I was of the understanding that it does not cache query results. Do you have a link to anywhere in the documentation that supports your claim?

Comment: checked it. there are two type of chache. In-context cache that caches it for only one http request. ( and policy to cache or not cache is explicitly needs to be set ) but it will not be cached in memcache. edit: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118 have more information.